# Jinja2 - How to get python None instead of string "None"

Tags: jinja2

In Jinja2 how to python None instead of string "None"?

```
{
  "value": "{{ example.value }}"
}
```

`example.value` may absent.

Answer (score 1):

If this is inside of a script tag, you can declare a constant at the beginning of the script:

```js
const None = null;
```

This will replace all of Python's `None` values that you pass to the template with JavaScript's equivalent `null`.

If this is rendering in the HTML itself, you can use:

```json
{
  "value": "{{ example.value if example.value }}"
}
```

This inserts a blank value if `example.value` is `None`.

Or you can use:

```json
{
  "value": "{{ example.value if example.value else 'No value!' }}"
}
```

Which inserts `No value!` if `example.value` is `None`.